# How to load a specific Stylesheet in my Wordpress template only when in RTL mode

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a Bootstrap3 built theme in WordPress, I'm working on translating and converting the theme from LTR to RTL.

So I want to load this stylesheet `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css` only on RTL mode on my Wordpress Theme.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [is_rtl()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_rtl) in your theme:

```
if ( is_rtl() ) {
  wp_enqueue_style(  'style-rtl',  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css' );
}
```

Comment: It becomes like this before the wordpress rtl function `<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-rtl-css'  href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/tdi/meris/wp-content/themes/meris/rtl.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.2" />`.

Comment: So I used this method and put the code under `<?php wp_head() ?>`. Her is what I used `<?php wp_head();?>
 <?php If( is_rtl () ) { echo '<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">'; } ?>`

Comment: Hi @Zaid_Sameer if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.